# Nix boost install misses headers

Tags: boost, nix

I installed boost using the nix package manager by `$ nix-env -i boost`, but there are no boost headers in current generation of my profile.

Thus `~/.nix-profile/include/boost` does not exit, but the boost library files can be found in `~/.nix-profile/lib`.

I searched in the nix store and found the headers in `boost-dev` folders within the store.

Why doesn`t nix link the boost headers into my current generation?

Comment: I've never seen `nix-env -i` used to install a library, usually it is used for executables.  What exactly do you mean when you say the headers are not in the current generation of your profile?  Can you show exactly what command you ran and say what its expected output is and what its actual output is?  Do you have an example of another library that installs its headers in your expected way?

Comment: eigen, qt5, opencsg, qscintilla.... using '-i' on these packages from nix-env produces header symlinks inside of ~/.nix-profile/include

Answer (score 5):

The `boost` package is a [split package](http://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#chap-multiple-output), so it has multiple outputs.

```
$ nix-instantiate --eval -E '(import <nixpkgs> {}).boost.outputs'
[ "out" "dev" ]
```

In this case the `out` output has the libraries, and the `dev` output has the headers. Normally the `dev` output is not installed to the user environment when you use `nix-env -i`. But it is used internally when the package is a build dependency of another package.

You can see what outputs will be installed like this:

```
$ nix-instantiate --eval -E 'builtins.toString (import <nixpkgs> {}).boost.meta.outputsToInstall'
"out"
```

The documentation indicates that you can override `meta.outputsToInstall` if you want other outputs.

My best attempt at doing this is:

```
nix-env -i -E \
  '_: with import <nixpkgs> {};' \
  'let newmeta = ( boost.meta // { outputsToInstall = ["out" "dev"]; } );' \
  'in boost // { meta = newmeta; }'
```

Would be interested to hear of a less cumbersome version...

I suspect the real answer is that we shouldn't be trying to install development stuff into the user environment. Perhaps it's better to write a `default.nix` file which defines development dependencies, and instantiate it with `nix-shell`. See for example https://garbas.si/2015/reproducible-development-environments.html.

Comment: for me the confusion is that on almost every other system ive used, from minix to freebsd to netbsd to linux to msys2 to cygwin, you install "user libraries" the same way you install "dev libraries", whether the package manager is pkgsrc, pkg, apt, rpm, dnf, etc, the only difference might be the package itself has "-dev" tacked on. i would like to learn the 'proper way' to do things in nix... but its a bit of a head scratcher at the first go for folks like me